# Обращение к фрейму во фрейме

Tags: jquery, javascript

Структура такая:

```
<body>
  // js код
  <frameset>
       <iframe name="main" src="demo.html">
           //внутри empty опять фрейм
           <frameset>
               <iframe name="content" src="demo.html">
                // контент
                </iframe>
           </frameset>
       </iframe>
  </frameset>
</body>
```

Как манипулировать контентом во фрейме `name="content"`?

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Политика безопасности.